# Cisco ASA 5505 not allowing OPC Traffic

Tags: firewall

I am integrating a Cisco ASA 5505 firewall in the following manner:

Inside IP range (VLAN-AWTP): 192.168.127.xxx (industrial devices)

DMZ IP range (VLAN-OPC): 192.168.77.xxx (only has OPC Server PC which accesses an industrial network device)

Outside IP range (VLAN-MWTP): 192.168.50.xxx (OPC client)

The purpose of the firewall is to **give VLAN-MWTP access to a PC on VLAN-OPC** (FULL access is ok), and **give limited access (single TCP port) from the OPC server to the industrial device**. This involves NATing and such which I think I have implemented ok.

Here's my current state of affairs and my issue:

-VLAN-OPC **can** access the VLAN-AWTP ok (can access TCP port on industrial device).

-A PC on VLAN-MWTP **can** ping and rdp to the VLAN-OPC server PC using NATed 192.168.50.32 (translates to 192.168.77.4), but it seems **it cannot browse or connect to the OPC server. I get the error *"The RPC server is unavailable"***

-I have isolated this to be a firewall issue, not Windows DCOM as is a common issue with OPC connections (had that struggle already!) I tested by setting IP of OPC PC to same subnet as MWTP-VLAN and bypassed firewall. Connected ok.

-I have tried a few different things such as enable DCERPC inspection as instructed by a few forums but still no joy, but by this point I feel out of my depth so I could very well be doing something wrong. You can probably see where my inspection policies start to get sloppy.

-Basically, I would be satisfied with total access (including RPC, DCOM, whatever) from VLAN-MWTP to VLAN-OPC. I wouldn't have thought it should be so hard??

Configuration is as follows:

```
ASA Version 8.2(5)
!
hostname AAA-AAAAA
enable password HxFQQ4ozRZkZGyAK encrypted
passwd HxFQQ4ozRZkZGyAK encrypted
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 100
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 200
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 300
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/4
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/5
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/6
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/7
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan100
 no forward interface Vlan300
 nameif VLAN-AWTP
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.127.4 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan200
 nameif VLAN-OPC
 security-level 0
 ip address 192.168.77.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan300
 nameif VLAN-MWTP
 security-level 0
 ip address 192.168.50.245 255.255.255.0
!
ftp mode passive
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object-group network opc-chw-ip
access-list opc-access-in extended permit tcp host 192.168.77.4 host 192.168.77.50 eq 44818
access-list vws-access-out extended permit tcp host 192.168.77.4 host 192.168.127.50 eq 44818
pager lines 24
mtu VLAN-AWTP 1500
mtu VLAN-OPC 1500
mtu VLAN-MWTP 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
static (VLAN-AWTP,VLAN-OPC) 192.168.77.50 192.168.127.50 netmask 255.255.255.255
static (VLAN-OPC,VLAN-MWTP) 192.168.50.32 192.168.77.4 netmask 255.255.255.255
access-group vws-access-out out interface VLAN-AWTP
access-group opc-access-in in interface VLAN-OPC
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa authentication telnet console LOCAL
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
telnet timeout 5
ssh 192.168.127.0 255.255.255.0 VLAN-AWTP
ssh timeout 60
console timeout 0

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
username aaaaaaaa password Tpz8OQBnrHIDp010 encrypted privilege 15
!
class-map icmp-class
 match default-inspection-traffic
class-map inspection-default
class-map CM-DCERPC
 match port tcp eq 135
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map icmp_policy
 class icmp-class
  inspect icmp
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect ip-options
  inspect netbios
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect skinny
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect tftp
  inspect sip
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect icmp
  inspect dcerpc
 class CM-DCERPC
  inspect dcerpc
policy-map PM-DCERPC
 class CM-DCERPC
  inspect dcerpc
!
service-policy global_policy global
service-policy icmp_policy interface VLAN-AWTP
service-policy PM-DCERPC interface VLAN-OPC
service-policy PM-DCERPC interface VLAN-MWTP
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  no active
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
  destination transport-method http
  subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
  subscribe-to-alert-group environment
  subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
Cryptochecksum:f545ff56444cbffecda9d652f2261e2d
: end
```

The OPC PC I am trying to connect to has static IP 192.168.77.4/24 with a gateway of 192.168.77.1 (this firewall).

Any help would be much, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the licence in use, but given the "no forward interface Vlan300" I'm assuming "Base" licence.

Anyway, why these statements?

```
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
...
access-list opc-access-in extended permit tcp host 192.168.77.4 host 192.168.77.50 eq 44818
...
access-group opc-access-in in interface VLAN-OPC
```

It seems they try to filter traffic between hosts on the same subnets, but this traffic shouldn't cross the firewall, should it? Who's 192.168.77.50? The only thing I can think is that you're trying to map the industrial device with an IP of OPC network... by doing "static (VLAN-AWTP,VLAN-OPC) 192.168.77.50 192.168.127.50 netmask 255.255.255.255" and by applying intra-interface and so on.

Also, both the fully-functional interfaces have same security level (0), and furthermore the service-policies applied to specific interfaces doesn't make a lot of sense for me.

Please don't get me wrong, but I'm just trying to figure out the overall picture.

Going to the possible solutions I can think:

1. Because there are different variants of RPC, and because RPC uses an End Point Mapper (EPM) to generate new connections for the client that start the requests on port 135 (similar to Active FTP behaviour), one possible problem might be related to the limited support of some RPC variants/messages of ASA versions < 9.4 (http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa94/release/notes/asarn94.html - "DCERPC inspection support for ISystemMapper UUID message RemoteGetClassObject opnum3"); depending by the calls used by your software (if non-EPM calls are used for instance), an upgrade could be necessary (keep in mind of the changes to the config statements, particularly from 8.3).
2. Given you told us that ping and RDP work but RPC, re-work the full config is probably not a great solution but I'll try to write a simpler one that might suite, assuming that:

   - You don't need NAT between internal networks that use private IP addressing (nat-control seems disabled indeed).
   - You don't need intra-interface communication.

```
ASA Version 8.2(5)
!
hostname AAA-AAAAA
enable password HxFQQ4ozRZkZGyAK encrypted
passwd HxFQQ4ozRZkZGyAK encrypted
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport nonegotiate
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 100
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport nonegotiate
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 200
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 switchport nonegotiate
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 300
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/4
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/5
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/6
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/7
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan100
 no forward interface Vlan300
 nameif VLAN-AWTP
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.127.4 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan200
 nameif VLAN-OPC
 security-level 20
 ip address 192.168.77.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan300
 nameif VLAN-MWTP
 security-level 90
 ip address 192.168.50.245 255.255.255.0
!
ftp mode passive
access-list vws-access-out extended permit tcp host 192.168.77.4 host 192.168.127.50 eq 44818
pager lines 24
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 3600
access-group vws-access-out out interface VLAN-AWTP
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
telnet timeout 5
ssh 192.168.127.0 255.255.255.0 VLAN-AWTP
ssh timeout 60
console timeout 0
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
username aaaaaaaa password Tpz8OQBnrHIDp010 encrypted privilege 15
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect ip-options
  inspect netbios
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect skinny
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect tftp
  inspect sip
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect icmp
  inspect dcerpc
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  no active
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
  destination transport-method http
  subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
  subscribe-to-alert-group environment
  subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
Cryptochecksum:f545ff56444cbffecda9d652f2261e2d
: end
```

I can't guarantee it works in your context of course, but the "debug dcerpc ?" and "packet tracer ?" commands can be useful to catch the errors on your live device.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response and sorry for the delay - I have a few projects on the go.
Yes, license is base license.
Yes, 192.168.77.50 is the NAT address of the industrial device I'm trying to connect to (192.168.77.50 translates to 192.168.127.50). 
While the addresses in that ACL are seemingly on the same subnet, one of the addresses is NATed and my testing showed that with that NATed traffic, that was correct ACL to use to restrict the traffic to that one port.

Comment: The arrangement of the same security traffic etc essentially is my best-effort result with the base license limitations. I went through a few iterations of designing this solution. It might be a bit convoluted (for myself) for me to work through my reasoning now but I'm fairly content with the architecture, especially given that rdp and icmp is working the way I expect it to.

To be honest, the service-policies don't make sense to me either at this point. They are the result of trial and error by going through various forums etc.

Comment: Intra-interface was added while debugging. I don't think it's necessary. RDP was working without it, but when I enabled it, ping started working. I think it has something to do with the NATing?

Thank you for a proposed solutions - I will investigate further with it in mind and will certainly get back.